# Run Tika source code from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-tika

I have been using Apache Tika for extracting text from different document formats. Now i want to make it handle header, footer and text boxes differently. So i downloaded source code of Tika from GitHub and trying to make changes in it.

I want to run Apache Tika source code from Eclipse and debug its execution by passing an input document. How can i do that? There are so many main classes. Where do i start? I understand its a Maven project and i am new to it.

And once i make changes how can i create new jar file?

Comment: maybe start with the [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/) then find an Eclipse Maven tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tika's xhtml output first, maybe it extracts headers/footers and you can use parser API to handle these parts as you wish. If it's that way, use API as [examples](http://tika.apache.org/1.14/examples.html) say passing custom SAX-like handler to it.

Comment: Yes it is extracting headers/footers, but it is not clear that the text is actually from headers/footers. So i wanted to add custom tags around text  from header/footer by digging into Tika source code.